# Changing TextBlock.Text via DataTrigger inside an ItemsControl

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol, textblock

In my WPF project I am trying to make an ItemsSource to display each element of an ObservableCollection, and display these as TextBlocks. Allthough I do need to alter the actual Text in some way, either with a converter or by Triggers. This whole ItemsControl is inside a ViewModel for different customers, which may have anywhere from none to a few different notes, stored in an ObservableCollection

My ItemsControl is set up like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}">
 <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

The ItemsPanelTemplate makes so that the Notes are horizontally oriented. And I have been trying to add a Style to the ItemsControl to change the TextBlock.Text, but since the Setters have lower priority it won't overwrite the original Text, allthough I can change font size and foreground color for instance. I am also not quite sure why this code even makes a TextBlock, as I have not specified this in any way. But as far as I have found out the ItemsControl will inherit some DataTemplate based on the type of the ItemsSource. I have also tried removing the ItemsPanelTemplate and replaced it with this

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
  <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
 </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

This will actually print out the word "Test", but it will not align itself horizontally, so on my screen it will not show (as I have limited screen real estate for this vertically). I have also not been able to figure out how I can use the ItemsSource to set the value of the TextBlock.Text provided in this last example, which I need to do to alter it (I have a set of rules of what to do with different notes).

TL:DR:
My ItemsControl prints out a TextBlock automagically that I need to change the text of, and I also need to keep the horizontal orientation. The first piece of code gives me the right orientation, but I can't figure out how to alter the text in any way. The second example has the wrong orientation, but I can manipulate the TextBlock.Text, but am struggling with the syntax to alter it the correct way.

Any help or pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: The Text property of the TextBlock in the ItemTemplate would usually be bound to a property in the item class, e.g. like `<TextBlock Text="{Binding YourTextProperty}"/>`. If the items are just strings, write `Text="{Binding}"`. However, *"the ItemsControl is inside a ViewModel"* sounds odd.

Comment: This worked like a charm! But how would I go about to alter the text? Could I put a Style with a trigger/setter after this? Or can I use a converter? Seems I can't type Text="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" at least.

Comment: Altering the text just means to change the Binding's source property, i.e. set YourTextProperty. The item class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged in order to notify about changed property values. The Binding converter shown in your comment should of course also work, provided that an appropriate resource exists.

Comment: I only want to alter the shown Text, not the ObservableCollection itself. I need the ObservableCollection to be left as is because of other functionality, but when displaying it I need to convert it a bit, as these can be a bit lengthy.

Comment: The Binding converter shown in your comment should of course also work, provided that an appropriate resource exists. However, the Binding is only reevaluated when the property actually changes.

Comment: It says "The character "," is unexpected at this position", as if I needed another parameter between binding and the ,Converter part.

Comment: `Binding YourTextProperty, Converter=...`

Comment: I just realized as you wrote it. It's been a long day...

Comment: This works! Thank you! Allthough it's just one more thing I can't get working now; the orientation. These insist on staying in a vertical orientation, but I need them to be horizontal. The first code snippet was how I fixed this issue before (before I found out I needed to alter the strings).

Comment: You'll have to declare both, ItemsPanel and ItemTemplate.

Comment: Oh, I could use them both, I had some errors earlier but that must have been something else. So close but yet so far away. Well, bless you for your time. This has been my nightmare all day, and finally I got a happy ending. Have a great day!